# Internet connection very slow only in my house and only with my Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, dns, internet

I bought a brand new MacBook Pro 13" 2015 (8GB RAM, i5, 128 SSD) 7 months ago. The thing is, my Mac works and I love it, but a couple of months ago, without doing anything, loading web pages even with Chrome as with Safari is extremely slow. My girlfriend has a Windows laptop and it works perfectly and when I connect to a different Wi-Fi router it works great. So my guess is there is a problem with my Mac related to my router.

I have tried several solutions already - I changed all of the DNS servers you can imagine in macOS and on my router as well, restarted my network settings, excellent namebench to see which is the right DNS for me, clearing caches... But nothing helped.

I must say that I don't have this problem 100% of the time, but more like 70% of the time. Sometimes it's like suddenly the problem goes away.
Speed test gives me 52.42 mbps download and 3.09 mbps upload and I always connect via Wi-Fi and not ethernet.

Follow-up:

This is the result of the following command:

```
ping -c 100 -s 1992 -q 192.168.1.1
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---  
100 packets transmitted, 20 packets received, 80.0% packet loss  
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.424/10.420/56.773/11.580 ms
```

80% packet loss sound like a lot. What should I exactly do with iStumbler?

Comment: Open Network Utilities and send 50 or 100 pings to 8.8.8.8 when your internet is giving you problems, and add the results (not all the pings, _please_) to your answer. You can also do the same when it's working ok, to compare.

Comment: What is your internet speed supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

### Internet or Wi-Fi problem

Open `System Preferences... > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced... > TCP/IP`
and note the IP address of your Wi-Fi router.

Let's say it is 192.168.1.1.

When you are in your bad network situation,
open a `Terminal` and enter the following command:

```
ping -c 100 -s 1992 -q 192.168.1.1
```

to check your Wi-Fi quality of connection and let run this command for nearly 2 minutes.
Make a copy of the result and include it in your question.

If is tells 0% packet lost, then your problem is a general Internet problem. If it tells your that you have some packets lost, then your
problem is on the Wi-Fi side.

I suspect that this might be your case.

### Analyse a Wi-Fi problem

Download the iStumbler software:

[iStumbler](https://istumbler.net/)

This version is free:

[iStumbler 99](https://istumbler.net/archive/release99/)

This is an excellent quality software and running without problem on from `Snow Leopard` to `Yosemite` (I didn't yet tested it on `El Capitan` or `Sierra`).

When you are in your bad network situation,
let `iStumbler` run for 10 minutes, order the output along the `Level`
column in decreasing order. Make a screen capture and include it in your question.

### IP or DNS problem

Open a `Terminal` and enter the following command:

```
dig www.apple.com
```

This command will ask your DNS server how it does resolve the `www.apple.com` in an IP address.

Include the output in your question.

Comment: Hey Daniel! Thanks a lot for the answer! Of course that my Internet suddenly is running out ok right now! But as soon as I have the issues again I will run the command and upload the answer here!